# Laravel: "debug" config dose not change

Tags: php, laravel

**Repreduce:**

In file `config/app.php` I changed following code

```php
'debug' => true,
```

After run `php artisan config:cache` command, I executed `dd(Config::get('app.debug'))`

**Expected:**

Get `true`

**Actual:**

Get `false`

---

You should to know when I changed other config, I got that except `debug`

Comment: How is the application running? Maybe that proces needs to be restarted too

Comment: Don't cache your config on a development system, you might need to change some setting and would need to cache over and over again. Cache your config on a production system. Use `php artisan cache:clear`, see if that works

Comment: There's not enough info to help us reproduce this. For example I cannot reproduce this in a fresh Laravel project. Where are you running the `dd(Config::get('app.debug'))` code? Are you sure no other code that runs before this (e.g. in a provider or middleware) overrides this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your `APP_ENV` is `development` or `testing` in `.env` file and run again following the command

`php artisan config:cache`

Like:

```bash
APP_ENV=development
```

Comment: fyi, caching config on dev systems is discouraged. From the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration#configuration-caching): "_You should typically run the php artisan config:cache command as part of your production deployment process. The command should not be run during local development as configuration options will frequently need to be changed during the course of your application's development._"

Answer (score 1):

Have you added

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
```

at top of file.
There is another way to check this, that is

```
dd(config('app.debug'));
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure there're no duplicate keys for `debug`